# I am getting an error when I am updating the post. It displays in the comment section but not update the post

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am making a simple blog site. But I am getting an error when I am updating the post. It displays in the comment section but not update the post.

Here is the code in_

**View.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm
from .models import Post, Author
from marketing.models import Signup

def get_author(user):
    qs = Author.objects.filter(user=user)
    if qs.exists():
        return qs[0]
    return None

def search(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(overview__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    context = {
        'queryset' : queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)

def get_category_count():
    queryset = Post \
        .objects \
        .values('categories__title') \
        .annotate(Count('categories__title'))
    return queryset

def index(request):
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:3]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
        new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'latest': latest
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def blog(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 4)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'queryset' : paginated_queryset,
        'most_recent' : most_recent,
        'page_request_var' : page_request_var,
        'category_count' : category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)

def post(request, id):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
                'id': post.id
            }))
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'post' : post,
        'most_recent' : most_recent,
        'category_count' : category_count,
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)


def post_create(request):
    title = 'Create'
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    author = get_author(request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = author
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", kwargs={
                'id': form.instance.id
            }))
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "post_create.html", context)

def post_update(request, id):
    title = 'Update'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(
        request.POST or None,
        request.FILES or None,
        instance=post)
    author = get_author(request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = author
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", kwargs={
                'id': form.instance.id
            }))
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'form': form
    } 
    return render(request, "post_create.html", context)


def post_delete(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    post.delete()
    return redirect(reverse("post-list"))
```

In **form.py**:

```
    class TinyMCEWidget(TinyMCE):
    def use_required_attribute(self, *args):
        return False


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'overview', 'content', 'thumbnail', 
        'categories', 'featured', 'previous_post', 'next_post')

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder' : 'Type your comment',
        'id' : 'usercomment',
        'rows' : '4',
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content', )
```

In **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce import HTMLField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

User = get_user_model()

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    overview = models.TextField()
    content = HTMLField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post-update', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })

    def get_delete_url(self):
       return reverse('post-delete', kwargs={
           'id': self.id
       })

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from posts.views import index, blog, post, search, post_create, post_update, post_delete

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('blog/', blog, name='post-list'),
    path('search/', search, name='search'),
    path('create/', post_create, name='post-create'),
    path('post/<id>/', post, name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<id>/update', post_update, name='post-update'),
    path('post/<id>/delete', post_delete, name='post-delete'),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In **post_create.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<div class="col-7 offset-3 mb-5 mt-5">
    <h2>{{ title }} a new Post</h2>
    {{ form.media }}
    <form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I would be happy if you please help me to solve the problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try running the form without crispifying it?

Comment: Updating post without cricrispy form same error. Updated content published in Comment Section

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your form to an instance of the model first, without saving it to the database, add author and finally save it:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            modelinstance = form.save(commit=FALSE)
            modelinstance.author = Author.objects.get(user=request.user)
            modelinstance.save()
```